# Magento: qual a melhor versão?

Tags: php, magento

Boa tarde, estou iniciando os estudos no e-commerce Magento e gostaria de saber de quem já tem alguma experiência com esta plataforma qual a melhor versão para ser utilizada. No caso, esta ultima versão 2.0.7 seria uma boa alternativa ou devo utilizar alguma versão anterior?

Obrigada.

Comment: a mais instavel sempre ou a que voce tem mais feicão

Comment: A versão dois do Magento está muito boa - gostei bastante. Mas, comercialmente não consegui utilizá-la. Um ponto que deve considerar é a disponibilidade de módulos. Tivemos dificuldades em encontrar módulos de pagamento e frete para os gateways brasileiros. Comercialmente ainda recomendo a 1.9.2.x.

Comment: @cbonomini obrigada pela resposta, estou em dúvida justamente por essa disponibilidade de módulos de pagamento, depois que instalei a última versão fiz uma pesquisa rápida e parece que está inviável comercialmente.

Comment: não entendi o porque da negativação da pergunta, fiz apenas porque não consegui encontrar publicações recentes sobre a última versão.

Comment: Quem o fez, deve pensar que as respostas aqui podem ser baseadas em opinião e não em fatos.

Answer (score 3):

Evite iniciar um negócio novo sob uma versão antiga de uma plataforma pois normalmente são defasadas, sem garantias e suporte. Terá ainda um custo de tempo e dinheiro relativamente grande com upgrades, sem contar os problemas oriundos de bugs que normalmente são corrigidos nas versões mais recentes.

Note que isso não vale somente para o Magento. Isso é válido para quaisquer plataformas.

Pode existir exceções onde será forçado a usar uma versão antiga, mas isso é muito raro e pode ser resolvido de formas mais inteligentes para que evite ao máximo o uso de algo defasado.

Adicionalmente, evite também "abandonar" a plataforma. Sempre que surgir um upgrade, faça-o num ambiente de testes e então atualize no ambiente de produção.
Portanto, uma vez instalado, precisa de manutenção constante. 
Essas plataformas populares estão sempre lançando novos updates numa média de 1 a cada 2 meses. Cada update desses traz mudanças diversas e normalmente correções contra bugs e também podem causar novos bugs que devem ser corrigidos o mais rápido possível.

Não deixe para fazer um upgrade depois de 1, 2, 3 anos, por exemplo, porque normalmente torna-se um pesadelo devido ao acúmulo de bugs inesperados.

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que presenciei de clientes e até cheguei a mecher com o Magento, salvo engano até fevereiro de 2016 o Magendo 1.9.1 era usado por grandes empresas(Walmart,Nike,ford). Porém as empresas de pagamento também tem que se readaptar para usar o novo 2.x. Então eu recomendo a 2.x pois logo as grandes empresas que utilizam devem migrar também, pois os plugins podem não ser mais criados pelos desenvolvedores e pela versão community, acarretando um custo maior para continuação da plataforma.

Validando também que existe integração do 1.9 para a 2.x para quem ainda é usuário da 1.9.